# Python Django - Show all assigned objects on the web page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, detailsview

I am developing web app for tracking orders. And I would like to display all orders which were created by a user via detailView.

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...    
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=150)

 class MyUser(models.Model):
    eid = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

views.py

```
     class UserDetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = MyUser
        template_name = "database/user_detail.html"


     def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.all().order_by("-id")
```

user_detail.html

```
     {% extends "base.html" %}
     {% block content %}
     <body>
         <h1> {{ user.eid }} {{ user.name }} {{ user.surname }} 
         </h1>
         {% for order in orders %}
             order.order_number
         {% endfor %}
      {% endblock %}
```

With this code I receive error: page not found: No Order found matching the query.

If i delete the `def get_queryset()` in the views.py, it shows only the users eid and name. Not sure how I can get all the assigned orders to the particular user.

Comment: If you want to list _ALL_ items (orders, users) you should use a `generics.ListView` instead of a `generics.DetailView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django allows you to follow relationships "backwards", meaning you can query all records of a modelB that has a FK or OneToOne relationship to your modelA.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)

...
modela = ModelA.objects.get(id=x)
queryset = modela.modelb_set()
```

That said, you can do this in your template:

```
{% for order in user.order_set.all %}... {% endfor %}
```

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: is this better, nether, faster or does it give more options than `generics.DetailView` ?  .. if so or not provide context around your answer. As given its aout-flagged by the bots for removal. (From Review).

Comment: @ZF007 is not better nor faster, it's different.  The DetailView is not the issue here, is the use of the ORM.

Comment: (much better answer with yout update; when you read this comment you can flag it for removal; no need to leave this personal feedback here for enternity).

Answer (score 2):

In the template try:

```
{% for order in user.order_set.all %}
    <p>{{ order.order_number }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This uses the foreign key relation to get the orders for a given `MyUser` instance.

The `get_queryset()` method is used to return a queryset in which to look for the object for the detail view.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code. The first one was mentioned by Higor Rossato in the comments, if you want to list mutiple things you should use a `generics.ListView`. You shoudl also change the `model` and `get_queryset` attributes of your view.

You want `model=Order` and

```
def get_queryset(self):
    Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-id")
```

then you should add a [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method to pass your user's information.